# textFieldShouldReturn is not called

Tags: objective-c, ios, keyboard

I want to make the keyboard disappear when the user clicks the "return" button,  I was told to use

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [tf resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

But nothing happens when I click the "return" button, the method isn't even being called. I am  doing this in

```
@interface gameOverMenu : UIView
```

not in the ViewController. I also don't use interface builder. What should I do?

Comment: Did you set the UITextField's delegate to the object that contains the method?

Comment: Have you designated your view controller a <UITextFieldDelegate>?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to make sure you implement the UITextFieldDelegate and set your UITextField delegate to self. In your .h file:

```
@interface gameOverMenu : UIView <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

And somewhere in your .m file (viewDidLoad: maybe):

```
self.yourTextField.delegate = self;
```

Now your -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField method should be called.

Comment: no problem. just fyi since i see you are new - it is common practice to mark my answer as correct if it is the one that helped you best. the reward system :)

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation

Comment: welcome to the most helpful coding community! thanks for the accept.

Comment: I find it really weird that despite dragging in IB to set the UITextField's delegate, you still have to do it in code for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have set the parent class (whatever it is) as a UITextFieldDelegate