# navigate through textfields

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to use the @PeyloW code that I found here [How to navigate through textfields (Next / Done Buttons)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347779/how-to-navigate-through-textfields-next-done-buttons) but when I press the keyboard **return** button nothing happens. My tags are ok.

Header:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField;
```

Implementation:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField {
    NSInteger nextTag = textField.tag + 1;
    UIResponder* nextResponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:nextTag];

    if (nextResponder) {
        [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];
    } else {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return NO;
}
```

What am I missing? My keyboard doesn't have next done, only return. Keep in mind that I'm very new to iOS.

EDIT:

I tried to debug the code by adding a breakpoint to it and the code isn't being triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like solutions that incorporate the tag. Instead I would put all inputfileds in the desired order into an array and in `-textFieldShouldReturn:` use the given textfield to get it's index from in the array. Then I would get the object at that index.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField {
    NSUInteger nextIndex = [arrayWithResponders indexOfObject:textField]+1 % [arrayWithResponders count];
    UIResponder* nextResponder = [arrayWithTextFields objectAtIndex: nextIndex];

    if (nextResponder) {
        [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];
    } else {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return NO;
}
```

---

You just added, that the breakpoints aren't triggered, so most likely you didn't set up the delegate.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm very new to iOS.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287131/textfieldshouldreturn-is-not-called

Comment: and of course: [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/ManageTextFieldTextViews/ManageTextFieldTextViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH10-SW1)

Comment: now It's working. Thank you for the tip and the piece of code. And I think you are right, keeping the controls in a array uses more memory but it's more maintainable.

Comment: If we had to worry about the memory consumption of an array, we all were doomed…